# Unable To Access Nested JSON Data from React Component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a map function that renders JSON data retrieved like this:

```
  <div className="items">
    {items.map(item =>
        <Card key={item.id} price={item.title} />)}
  </div>
```

It successfully iterates over and renders data from un-nested properties, but I am having trouble getting it to render the USD nested prop as shown here:

```
     "price":{  
        "amounts":{  
           "GBP":"£8,185",
           "USD":"$12,000",
           "EUR":"€10.755"
        },
```

I am trying to extract it like this:

```
  <div className="items">
    {items.map(item =>
        <Card key={item.id} price={item.price.amounts.USD} />)}
  </div>
```

And the error message I'm getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'amounts' of null." I have also tried with square brackets to no success.

Comment: is there any price inside array that have null value? do console.log('data', items); and show the result.

Comment: Do all items from the JSON data contain a price property?  Does the code fail if there is only one item with all properties set?

Comment: Ahhhhh yes some of them do. How would I circumvent this? Just tried to set a default value of 0 but still throwing me that error.

Comment: use this: `price={item.price? (item.price.amounts||{}).USD||0: 0}`

Comment: You ROCK! If you want to leave that as an answer I'll mark it correct. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Something to consider is what it means in your project for an item to have no price.  Does that indicate that the item is free, or that the item is not for sale?  `null` may be a perfectly valid price if the item is not intended for sale, and thus may need to be handled differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, some of the price values are null (all the item doesn't contains the price object), thats why it is throwing error:

> Cannot read property 'amounts' of null.

Solution is, put the check before accessing the amount property, Like this:

```
price={item.price? (item.price.amounts||{}).USD||0 : 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer above is 100% correct (and recommended) I would consider using `_.get` *if* you are already using lodash:

```
import get from 'lodash/get'

// in render
// the third argument is the default price is *any* of the path is not defined
price={ get(item, 'price.amounts.USD', 0) }
```

For me, the pathing system in lodash (get, has, set) are extremely expressive and result in much more readable code. If you are importing just `get` (using the above import, instead of `import { get } from lodash`) the size footprint is also quite small.

#### Update:

An interesting comment by @SimianAngel - 100% correct regarding the default value. 0 is probably not what you want as a default value! Depending on your business logic of course.

Again leveraging the path methods of lodash, creating something readable and expressive is quite simple:

```
import get from 'lodash/get'
import has from 'lodash/has'

// in render
<div>
  {has(item, 'price.amounts.USD')) 
    ? <Card key={item.id} price={get(item, 'price.amounts.USD'} />
    : <div>This item isn't available in this region</div>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not using lodash but will definitely look into that for next time. Thanks!

Comment: No worries at all